# How to use bold and italics in pastebin?

Tags: pastebin

How to use bold and italics in pastebin?
So far I'm just able to highlight complete lines in yellow.
I have a pro account. I wouldn't mind using different colors with my pro account either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, paste bin is for plain text code, and it will highlight your code according to the chosen code syntax highlighting.

Comment: I've got a Word document I want copied in pastebin. Is there one syntax highlighting that will copy it the exact same way?

Comment: Or can I choose what to highlight?

Comment: No, you can't copy it the exact same way. Paste bin is basically for code, not office documents. The closest would be to convert it to markdown (PRO feature).

Comment: It would be much better if you'll describe your problem/situation and let people help you, instead of trying to solve your not fitting solution. [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: I just made use of the markdown language as you suggest, and I can use bold, italics, headings and highlight text in grey. Can I also use different colors?

Comment: No, you can't. This is not the purpose. If you want, I'd suggest you'd ask for the thing you actually want, and not how to make your unfitting solution work... My answer answers your question, since it's not possible.

Comment: Ok, just to make sure, in markdown language I can use bold, italics, make links, change size of text, highlight in grey and use boxes. But using several colors is not possible?

Comment: Basically markdown has its own rules, and just coloring is not one of them. You have syntax highlight for code, and some environments support embedding some html tags, which if available, can be used to color the text by demand.